# Django ChoiceField changes Input from False to True

Tags: python, django

In Django, I have a `ChoiceField` that looks like this:

```
completed = forms.ChoiceField(choices = COMPLETED_CHOICES, required = True)
```

Here's the `COMPLETED_CHOICES`:

```
COMPLETED_CHOICES = (
    ('', ''),
    (True, "Yes"),
    (False, "No")
)
```

This is my model.py:

```
completed = models.BooleanField(choices = COMPLETED_CHOICES)
```

My problem is that every time I make a new instance, if I chose "`No`" on the form, the value will be saved as True. Meanwhile, if I chose "`Yes`", it'll save as True, which works as expected. Why is "`No`" only being affected?

Here's the relevant part of views.py

```
completed = form.cleaned_data['completed']

book = Book(
    completed = completed,
)

book.save()
```

Comment: add `print completed` under `completed = form.cleaned_data['completed']` and let us know what is printed out when you select both "Yes" and "No" in your form.

Comment: `print(completed)` gives me False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **False** value is probably passed from a form as a string. Take a look at the following code:

```
>>>print False  
False 
>>>
>>>print "False"  
False
>>>
>>>
>>>if False:
...    print 1
>>>
>>>if "False":
...    print 1
1
```

Then you will need to parse the value from string by using for example

```
completed = form.cleaned_data['completed'] == 'True'
```

You can always check the type of given value by using **type( form.cleaned_data['completed'] )**